# Loading Hive tables from Talend

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, talend

We are using Talend as ETL tool to extract data from a Hive database tables and load it to a different Hive database table. Can someone suggest the correct Talend components to do the above task?

Extract data from Hive Table A in Database D1 ---> Load data to Hive Table B in Database D2.

I used tELTHive components but there seems to be some restrictions in it. Also Is there a way to load data to Hive Tables without loading the extracted data to a file before writing it to a Hive table.